# How to align checkboxes created using roles to the center of the cell in QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, checkbox, qtablewidget

In my Qt C++ Windows application, I create checkboxes in my table using roles:

```
QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();
item->setData(Qt::CheckStateRole, QVariant::fromValue(dev.is_active ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked));
ui.tableWidget->setItem(i, ui_columns_positions.at(table_columns::IsActive), item);
```

The problem is that checkboxes are left-aligned. I need to align them to the center of the cell.
[image: left-aligned checkboxes]

I've already tried various alignment methods, but none of them work. For example, I created a style for alignment, I made a delegate class - nothing worked.
How to align checkboxes created using roles to the center of the cell in QTableWidget?

Comment: You could use stylesheets and customize the item's checkbox using `QTableWidget::item:indicator` and set a left margin to center it, but that would be applied to all of your items, which leads to their text being pushed off the right edge and hidden. Could you use a `QCheckBox` and use [QTableWidget::setCellWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget)? That would allow you to customize a single item at a time using style sheets.

Comment: @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene, yes, I can use QCheckBox, but then there is a problem with highlighting the entire row when clicking on some cell: I can’t highlight the entire row along with the checkbox